# Phone isn't recognized by ADB

Tags: android, adb

this whole thing is a nightmare, at least in windows. I had my phone connected and everything was ok. I have a Samsung Galaxy, I've installed the USB driver and it was okay, I could run apps from eclipse directly on my phone. 
Now nothing is differentm but when I type adb devices it recognizes my phone but its offline.
USB debug option is checked, and I have the right drivers installed. 
Any idea?
thanks!

Comment: im guessing you have tried unplugging and replugging, restarting your computer, unchecking and rechecking usb debug, the usual?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer and phone?

Answer (score 5):

I ve seen multiple times this problem and there is no common answer. i'll make a list of solutions that I have seen across severals forums:

- Restart ADB server with the following commands: `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`
- Change the USB cable you are using: I've seen a lot of complaints about Samsung's USB cable.
- Change the USB socket you are using
- Try to reinstall the drivers (for instance, for Samsung devices, installing Kies; this solved the problem for me)
- Try to reboot your phone
- Unset the `debug mode` on the device and set it again

Adb seems to often cause troubles, not the best piece of software I've seen!

Comment: Tried each one of these, unsetting debug mode and resetting it worked!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your phone's SD card isn't mounted as a drive on your Windows machine. Whenever that happens to me, I can't connect via adb.

Comment: This worked for me too with a ZTE phone, under Mac OS X 10.6.7. Just ejected the 'driver disk' and up it popped. Flabbergasting!

Comment: Yes. This was exactly my issue. My device (LG Enlighten) said it could connect as "Charge Only", "Storage", or "Modem". I had always had it auto-connect as storage, but if you want to use ADB you have to use it as a modem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting the adb server?

Run:

```
adb kill-server    
adb start-server    
adb devices
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you also tried to change the USB socket in which you plugged the USB cable?

Sometimes one thinks about unplugging/replugging, but not about changing the USB socket in which to plug the cable. All the more since it is correctly recognized by Windows.

I had the same symptoms (Windows recognizing my Samsung Galaxy, but not ADB), and changing the place where I plugged the USB cable did worked for me.