# ZTE V9 not detected by ADB

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I've spent over an hour trying to make ADB detect my ZTE V9 on **Ubuntu 11.04**. It's not a permissions issue, *adb devices* simply doesn't print anything

```
List of devices attached
```

USB debugging is on

This is what my android rules look like

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2:0083" SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev" TEST=="/var/run/ConsoleKit/database", \ RUN+="udev-acl --action=$env{action} --device=$env{DEVNAME}"
```

This is the output of *lsusb*

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 19d2:0083 ONDA Communication S.p.A. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
...
```

After editing android.rules I've restarted udev and restarted adb.

I've tried several modifications of this udev rule. I've also tried to use 99-android.rules instead of 51, but nothing changes.

Then, I've tried to manually edit ./android/adb_usb.ini, which after my edit looks like this

```
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x19d2
```

But still, the device is not detected.

Up to now I have developed for a Samsung Galaxy S, which is detected inmediately

Thanks in advance!

sources used up to now:

[XDA-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11823740)

many other web sites

Comment: This may seems stupid, but may be `ATTR{idVendor}` instead of `ATTRS{idVendor}`?

Comment: Sorry guys, none of the answers helped me, but thanks a lot for trying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just went through all these same steps with a ZTE V768 (concord), with the same results as you -- adb just showed nothing.  The same udev rules I've used for every other phone just don't work for this one.

Then I found this thread:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1853571&page=8

Looks like ZTE conveniently leaves a driver install file somewhere on their phones (mine was in /system/data/PCSUITE.ISO, or someone mentioned /dev/PCSUITE.ISO), which has a linux script to set up some udev rules for it. I ran their 'install', then 'adb devices' immediately after, and it was there.

Their 'driver' consists of copying 2 rules files to /etc/udev/rules.d/, copying adb to /usr/bin, and running 'chmod a+x' on all three of those files.  I removed the executable permissions from the rules files and removed their installed adb, and I'm still able to connect to the phone, so I believe only the rules should be necessary.

So, here they are:

---

**51-android-hs.rules:**

```
# for android device

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666"
```

**61-usb-cdrom-hs.rules:**

```
# This file maintains persistent names for CD/DVD reader and writer devices.
# See udev(7) for syntax.

############################################################################
SUBSYSTEM=="block", SYSFS{idVendor}=="19d2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0358", SYMLINK+="ZTECdrom", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/eject /dev/ZTECdrom", RUN+="/bin/eject /dev/ZTECdrom"
############################################################################
```

---

I haven't done any more research into why this works (is the cdrom rule necessary, is the phone being recognized as a cdrom device somehow?  Is there a difference between using 'SYSFS' as opposed to 'ATTR'?  or does the rule just need to be before the stock rules for this phone?)
...  but these are the 'official' ZTE udev rules, and it works.

In case it matters, this was for a ZTE Concord which shows a product ID of '0355' in lsusb, and I don't have a device with a product ID of '0358' as the cdrom rule lists. Again, not sure if this is relevant, just sharing in case it is.

And if you want the full driver install, it's probably on your phone in /system/data/PCSUITE.ISO or /dev/PCSUITE.ISO, or there's a link to download it in the XDA thread above.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this sounds promising. I no longer own that device, but I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: A couple of important addendums to this answer: 

1) Everywhere that you find 'SYSFS' in the udev rules should be changed to 'ATTR'. This seems to be a legacy issue with udev, but my system threw errors at every boot when I had 'SYSFS' in the rules.

2) You missed an important thing that the install "driver" does. At the very end, it ejects all devices that start with 'sr'.


This is the same thing that everyone else keeps noting, so I am inclined to believe running the install script succeeds for the same reason: that it ejects your phone. Re-running this eject part solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This answered my problem (which is similar to yours Maraguez)
[Phone isn't recognized by ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390951/phone-isnt-recognized-by-adb)

Basically your computer is using the mobile device as a USB drive, you figure out how to eject or disable, and it'll pop up in adb.

Comment: Hi Anna, I don't own that device anymore, so I can't test it to accept your answer, but thanks for the tip, it may help others

Comment: No problem, if people read this far they'll figure it out, ha

Comment: This worked for me. After ejecting, Win8 popped up a dialog for installing device drivers. Was able to detect the device after that.

Comment: I think this is the answer a lot of people are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Two things, maybe:

1. Why your udev rule so complicated? Does it work with the simpler rule given [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up) ? Not sure if its relevant (i don't know much on udev), but the previous link tells to only put the vendor id in `{idVendor}`, without the device id.
2. This may seems stupid, but did you turn on USB debugging on the device? I got stuck on this some times ago.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've used both simple and complex rules, none of which works. And yes, USB debugging is on :(

Answer (score 1):

Add in the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file only this line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19D2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that's the first thing I tried as it's in the official documentation. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked "eject" and it appeared in "adb devices" command

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with the ZTE Warp Sequent by:

Setting the Connection Type on the device to "PC Software."

Going to "My Computer" and Right clicking USB_DRIVER, and selecting "Open."

Finally I found some executables inside, I ran them and viola! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

A powered USB hub helped me with a certain device. Maybe the current from the USB port is not adequate for that USB device,

Comment: Thanks, but that same device is detected by other computers with my same usb data cable. Was yours detected?

Comment: Yes, I had no issues with the device on other computers. Every combination worked except that particular device with that particular  machine. If you have a powered hub, try that. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or... you can do

`sudo mkdir /media/(userneame)/sr1`

then

`sudo mount /dev/sr1`

This will mount a cd img, go into cd using "your file explorer" under linux Folder in the cdrom extract Usb_Driver, then in terminal cd to the Usb_Driver folder and type in

`sudo ./install`