# add my ZTE warp to machine for android development

Tags: android

I'm having trouble adding my ZTE warp to my desktop machine for android development.

I've been editing the `51-android.rules` file with no luck.  I'm currently adding this line for my phone:

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"`

but upon entering the command:

`adb devices`

I get the following output:

"List of devices attached
 ???????? no permissions"

Is there anyone who could suggest a way to edit my .rules file to get this to run?  Thanks for any help!

p.s. it seems like someone else had this problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909011/zte-v9-not-detected-by-adb) but it was not resolved.

Comment: Have upvoted this to make sure this will get on top of the pile of search results for others who will undoubtedly come across it and experiencing frustration with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added yourself to the plugdev group?

```
sudo usermod user_id -G plugdev -a
```

Replace user_id with your own Linux id that you use to login.

Also, I have this in mine:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1351", MODE="0666" GROUP="androiddev", SYMLINK+="android%n"
```

And log out and log in again for the additional group to kick in. If not working, reboot or restart udev :)

***Edit:*** As it turned out the OP's group id was replaced with plugdev and ended up not in sudoers list - my bad! I left out the critical switch **-a**! All I can say is oops! :)

Comment: Nice catch. I just did that; I still encounter the same problem though.

Comment: Have you actually done **lsusb** to determine the right endpoint? on mine, its - "*Bus 001 Device 010: ID 19d2:1351 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM*" and yeah its Zte Blade :D

Comment: Also you're missing the idProduct in your rule as well :)

Comment: yep, i did the `lsusb` to ensure the right idProduct!  I'm trying the suggestions now =]

Comment: thanks a bunch!  working...=] However, I now seem to be out of the `sudoers` group...any fix?

Comment: Glad to be of help mate :) Have fun with your Zte Warp :)

Comment: Sh!t... my fault! I forgot the append switch... -a to usermod! Will edit this accordingly, do this - *su*, enter password for root, from there, *usermod user_id -g users -G plugdev -a*, then *exit*

Comment: alright, thanks there.  I'll just boot into recovery and add myself to admin again.  But definitely change so others don't make the same mistake!