# ADB doesn't recognize android phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

after I reinstalled my eclipse & android sdk, the adb won't recognize my phone! I've already tried out to restart the server & plug on and off the cable several times. I also don't think its a driver problem. Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: Show log file and errors. Then try remove/reinstall Phone's driver.

Comment: Please see [the answer provided here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12018562/154306).

Comment: i see, does anybody know where to get the drivers for htc phones except from the sdk manager ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you [install the OEM Drivers](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)?
Did you turn on USB debugging on your device?

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked for me, but only for my nexus 4, my htc desire z is still dead. the exlorer says that it was unable to install the google usb drivers, how is that possible ?

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the same problem with your tip!

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing on Windows and would like to connect an Android-powered device to test your applications, then you need to install the appropriate USB driver.

Do that for newest version.

[image]

Comment: i have already installed them, there has to be another issue.